# Keycloak multitenant with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, multi-tenant

I have a scenario where we have one keycloak which will be used to login from multiple tenants ... multiple different domains. We are using spring boot on backend with oauth spring security (spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server) so no keycloak adapter but spring boot oauth

1.) ech tennant will have one domain login should be possible via different domains
2.) in the backend I have the option to setup one domain as keycloak.url ... can mutitennancy even work if the tokens will be issued from different domains.